# Resolving a JQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

I've managed to create the following page which has a iOS Slider working alongside BGStretcher, with a bit of script controlling the conflict between the two libraries used. However, I now want to add in a further JQuery library to create the "puff" effect on a div.

The problem is, when I add in the puff code I have, it breaks the page and none of the libraries will work. Below is a link to the iOS Slider and BGStretcher page I've created with a further link showing the puff test document (please excuse the simplicity for the moment, I am simply trying to get it working ).

www.psychobeing.co.uk/2012/demo/index.html

www.psychobeing.co.uk/2012/demo/pufftest.html

I've tried reordering the scripts and adding in the noConflict script below between the puff effect script and the others but it still doesn't work, if anything it means nothing works! Any help would be much appreciated!

From what I can tell there is a conflict between the iOSSlider and BGStretcher scripts and the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
```

Below is the latest version with everything included (including the above lines)

http://www.psychobeing.co.uk/2012/demo/index2.html

If anyone can help me out I'd really appreciate it!

Cheers!

Comment: How exactly are you using `noConflict()`? Please include the relevant code here. How to use multiple jQuery versions is thoroughly explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing 1 of the jquery in there? right now you are using 2  versions.
1.5.2 and 1.6.1.

Can you try using 1.7.1 instead? I think your other plugins would still work as they said 1.6+ compatible

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You use NoConflict if you use other library together with jquery. for example, Mootools and jquery.

for more info
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 versions of jquery man. Pretty sure that will cause problems.